# using aero.animation for video

Tags: matlab, animation, aero

I'm trying to use aero.animation to animate a missile motion in matlab.
When I use the following code it plays the video but saves only the first frame.

*`data` is in form of `[time, x, y, angle]` matrix where all `time`, `x`, `y` and `angle` are `nx1` vectors which I calculated beforehand. In my case `n = 1312` and I've taken `x` and `y` as zeros of column vectors. `angle` is the fifth column of `SOLUTION` which is a matrix of 1312x7, I had calculate before.

```
data = [time, zeros(length(time), 1), zeros(length(time), 1), SOLUTION(:, 5)];
h=Aero.Animation;
f=figure;
h.Figure=f;
h.initialize();
h.FramesPerSecond=10
h.TimeScaling = 5;
idx1=h.createBody('testrocket.ac','ac');
h.bodies{1}.TimeseriesSourceType='Array3DoF';
h.bodies{1}.timeseriesSource=data;

h.Camera.offset=[-150 -150 0];
h.show()

h.VideoRecord = 'on';
h.VideoQuality = 50;
h.VideoCompression = 'Motion JPEG AVI'
h.VideoFilename = 'astMotion_JPEG';
h.play()
h.VideoRecord='off';
```

The code looks like this now, yet the video still recording same image for few seconds insted of recording the actual video with the missile movment. ( when i play the record video it shows like frozen situation).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution but you have to know the time duration of your animation.

Now your problem is caused by running `h.VideoRecord = 'off';` command shortly after `h.play` command but `h.VideoRecord = 'off';` command doesn' t wait for the previous command finish. Anyway you can use `pause()` function to avoid the problem.

```
% // ...
h.play()
pause(timeDurationOfAnimation) % // timeDurationOfAnimation -> time unit in seconds
h.VideoRecord = 'off';
```

**EDIT:** Time duration of animation/video depends on you specified values of `FramesPerSecond` and `TimeScaling` properties.

[`The combination of FramesPerSecond and TimeScaling property determine the time step of the simulation. Your settings result in a time step of approximately 0.5 s.`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/aerotbx/ug/using-aero-animation-objects.html)

---

+++  **More Explanation:**
My `data` is 100x4 matrix means length of `time` vector is 100. Time resolution is 0.1 second so time vector like that `Time = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ..., 9.8, 9.9, 10]'`. If I use your time set up which is `FramesPerSecond = 10` and `TimeScaling = 5`, I get 2 seconds of video. Because `TimeScaling = 5` means display 5 data pack in per second, but one data pack contains 10 frames so according to your set up animation displays 50 frame per second. My whole `data` contains 100 frames so 100/50 = 2 seconds so time duration of animation/video is 2 seconds. Remember `TimeScaling` is due to speeding up the animation and you record your animation as speeded up one.

My suggestion is that specify value of `FramesPerSecond` according to frequency of your `Time` update:

```
% // ...
h.FramesPerSecond = 1 / ( data(2, 1) - data(1, 1) ) % // According to my Time resolution that would be 10;
h.TimeScaling = 1;
% // ...
pause( data(end, 1) )
h.VideoRecord = 'off';
```

Comment: it helped me to get video of few seconds but still the image it shows in the whole video is the first frame.its like the video recording 30 seconds the same frame.

Comment: first of all thanks for your help, i tried to do what you said and it plays the video in matlab slower than before and it recorded like 5 minutes of video. the old problem still exists that when i play the video i recorded in media player for example it shows me 5 minutes the same image.

Comment: @ben - You' re welcome ben, no problem :) Actually, your original problem has been solved. You aren' t recording only one frame anymore. On the other side you can use as `TimeScaling = 5` and `FramesPerSecond = 10`. You can omit `pause( data(end, 1) )` and 
`h.VideoRecord = 'off';` commands. Having finished animation, write these commands to command window.. I had just given extra explanation about how `TimeScaling` and `FramesPerSecond` work..

Comment: its probably recording more than 1 frame, but the problem is that when the video is playing it shows same image. lets say i dont see any motion of the missile only its first position at the recorded file.

Comment: @ben - Don't worry I see you, I've just supposed that it showed the same image only when you had used the set ups which I had suggested. Anyway, I've reproduced the case and I've seen movements of missile. I suppose this is because missile flew over hundreds of kilometers in my case. Thus, your new problem must be caused by scale of missile comparing to your trajectory range and camera position (includes zoom out factor). Actually, I haven't used "aero.animation" before so I have nothing to say but you should take a look at scale of missile. Good luck ben..